# What does "crust" mean in the following passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This pizza tastes really nice. The **crust** is crunchy on the outside and soft on the inside.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because googling will show it.

Comment: @Lambie: Appearance on Google is [not actually a valid close reason](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/ask-even-if-the-answer-exists-online) (almost anything can show up there if you know what to search for), but appearance in a dictionary *is*.

Comment: Pizza crust is a simple vocabulary question. What effort did the OP make to find it? I still am voting to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crust is the tough outer part of a loaf of bread or anything that's made of out flour and then baked, including pizza dough which you use as the base for your pizza on which you put other ingredients such as onions, slices of salami, slices of tomato, cheese, mudrooms and so on and so forth.

The crust is crunchy on the outside means that it makes a sharp noise when it's bitten or crushed. And the crust is soft on the inside means exactly what it says—it's soft inside. All this information is easily googable, by the way. Here's a picture of a pizza crust:

[image: a cheese pizza]